# Cognos date prompt for specific hours not working as expected

Tags: db2, cognos

I'm trying to create a report with date prompt. I need a result with 11AM to 11AM data; the query I have written is;

```
((date(lastupdatetime)  = (#prompt('Parameter1')#)  and HOUR(Cast(lastupdatetime as TimeStamp))>=11) 
or (date(lastupdatetime) = (#prompt('Parameter2')#) and HOUR(Cast(lastupdatetime as TimeStamp))<= 11))
```

But is is returning whole day data. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please, provide some sample data with the `lastupdatetime` column and parameters values you get unexpected result with.

Comment: So if Parameter1 = 2019-09-01 and Parameter2 = 2019-08-01, you want to see lastupdatetime values that are between 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 and 2019-08-01 11:00:00.000 or between 2019-09-01 11:00:00.000 and 2019-09-01 23:59:59.999?

Answer (score 1):

The following example will return a 24 hour period starting at 11AM from a user prompted date.

```
[Date] between #
prompt('FromDate','date')+' 11:00:00.000-05:00'
#
and
#
_add_hours(prompt('FromDate','date')+' 11:00:00.000-05:00',24)
#
```